# can dd be used to wipe clean a directory?

Tags: linux, dd, linux-mint

I have a directory on a Mint install that I want to wipe clean (not just delete the pointers, actually zero the info off the drive).  is it possible to clear the data by using `dd`?  For example, if the files I want to erase are at `/folder/folder1/*`, can I execute `dd if=/dev/zero of=/folder/folder1 bs=1k` and have that zero all files in that directory?  Also, if I have subdirectories, will it work recursively to zero all subfolders as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use find and dd together to recursively write over files, one at a time:

```
find /folder/folder1 -type f | while read line; do dd if=/dev/zero of=$line bs=1k count=1024; done
```

Then you can just rm -rf the parent directory:

```
rm -rf /folder/folder1
```

This will by no means be a quick process, but it will get the job done. There are certainly better tools out there than using dd for this.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `dd` for folder, which is for devices such as a partition or a file. If it is Ubuntu, you should install `shred`, which is designed for what you want to do.

Shred works on files only, so you want to do:

```
find /folder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 shred
```

You can use `shred` on partitions as well.

There are many other tools if you are not on Ubuntu. `shred` may be available for other distros as well.

You can also just google for deleting files securely in Linux, or something like that, to find more tools that may better suit your needs.

Comment: mint has different code bases, with some based on ubuntu/debian, that is why i am not too clear what packages are available for yours. i am pretty sure shred is available for the current mint.

Comment: Thanks! It is noteworthy that shred only works on files, not on folders.  I solved this by executing `find /folder/folder1 -type f | xargs shred`

Comment: To be safe, you want to use `print0` as a `find` option and pass `-0` to ´xargs` @ewok

Comment: On CentOS/Fedora you'll need to install `coreutils`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use dd to securely delete a  directory, but you can use [`wipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wipe).

> wipe repeatedly overwrites special patterns to the files to be destroyed, using the fsync() call and/or the O_SYNC bit to force disk access

Comment: ... can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

I use `srm`, which is in the `secure-delete` package on Ubuntu and Debian. `sudo apt-get install secure-delete` to install it, then `srm -r $directory` to securely remove an entire directory tree. `srm` won't overwrite non-regular files, but it will (by default) rename all files and directories to a random value before unlinking them.

You can use the `-z` flag to have it write zeros for the last pass and `-v` to see its progress. See `man srm` for more information.